# rendering a user control to a string

Tags: asp.net

I'm using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258877/load-a-user-control-programmatically-in-to-a-html-text-writer/259791#259791) to render a User Control to a string and it all works fine when the control contains just plain HTML, but when I try adding some server controls to the UC (like asp:button) I get the following error when calling server.execute:

> "Error executing child request for
>   handler 'System.Web.UI.Page'."

any ideas why/how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: Attach Visual Studio to the w3wp.exe process and break on all managed exceptions (ctrl-alt-e). This would give you (and us) more information about stack trace and error messages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the UC should have been added to the form's control collection, not the page's.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to include a call to `EnsureChildControls()` before to render to a string. This way you force the page to render the entire control tree first.