# Changing displayed data from a static method in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-methods

I have two user controls that sit on a page which determines which should be displayed. The user controls generate some html that is passed into an asp:literal and subsequently manipulated via javascript. It is done this way due to the lack of a suitable control that I am allowed to use on the project.

When a user clicks a view change button, a WebMethod is called on the main page (the one that holds the controls) from the control's javascript. From here, a static method on the control is called. The control then needs to regenerate the html and place it into the asp:literal for the view change to be complete.

My problem is that I am in a static method on the control's page, and have no access to the non-static genorateHtml function. I have tried a singleton pattern with no success (this could have been due to improper implementation).  Any ideas on how to make this call? THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I used to hit similar issues at with one of the projects i worked on. The solution we ended up adopting was implementation of System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler with partial rendering to return just the needed content depending on arguments. ICallbackEventHandler runs in the page lifecycle.

The only trouble we had then was performance issues relative to implementation which posts back the whole form instead of just the arguments you want.

Maybe the best way for you would be through [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258877/load-a-user-control-programmatically-in-to-a-html-text-writer) in which they render the control from a static method. That would probably suit your needs.

Hope this helps!